# Linear Layout with imageviews doesn't appear after inflating

Tags: java, android, layout-inflater

I have a linear layout that I would like to show in an activity.  Here's the code that I use for doing that:

```
final LayoutInflater factory = getLayoutInflater();
final View ps = factory.inflate(R.layout.photo_shooting, null);
final RelativeLayout photoshooting = (RelativeLayout) ps;

//other code...

rscroll.addView(photoshooting, lp);
```

and the layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/photoshooting"
android:background="@drawable/dropdownborder">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:id="@+id/selectedphoto" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/camera_and_film">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:id="@+id/camera"
        android:background="@mipmap/camera" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:id="@+id/cameraroll"
        android:background="@mipmap/cameraroll" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

The problem is that it doesn't appear when I add it to the relative layout rscroll.  Why can't I see it when I run?

Comment: Accordingly to what you posted, `final RelativeLayout photoshooting = (RelativeLayout) ps;` will make your app crash for ClassCastException

Answer (score 1):

It could be because your RelativeLayout has the id "@+id/photoshooting" but you are adding "R.layout.photo_shooting" to your code.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that I wasn't casting to the correct layout like Blackbelt mentioned.  It should be:

```
LinearLayout photoshooting = (LinearLayout) ps;
```